# Python script: Cannot extract line from a list

Tags: python, arrays, split, serial-port, substring

I am reading some values via serial and need to extract specific line and republish the value later on.
So far I am sucked with extraction of the value. Currently my output consists of list of 4 variables and only 1 element.
I want to declare a set of 4 new variables with respective value being read from each of them in a loop.
split() is not bringing me any further and I am not able to get rid of redundant lines in a step to declare individual variable. Can you please advise how can I proceed further to declare individual variable values out of the string list?

My current output is a list and it looks like list (1 column) as follows:

```
19.63
1.0
1.0
1.0
```

[image: output]

```
#!/usr/bin/env python
import time
import serial
import re
ser = serial.Serial(
    port='/dev/ttyUSB0',
    baudrate = 9600,
    parity=serial.PARITY_NONE,
    stopbits=serial.STOPBITS_ONE,
    bytesize=serial.EIGHTBITS,
    timeout=1
)
while 1:
    xa=ser.readline()
    if len(xa) > 0:
         xb=filter(lambda x:  not re.match(r'^\s*$', x), xa)
         rows = xb.split('\n')
         for row in rows:
              value = row.split(":")[0]
              try:
                 value=float(value)
                 print(value)
              except:
                 pass
```

Comment: `xb` is not a string, you can't use `xb.split()`

Comment: Your code doesn't make much sense. `xa` is one line, why do you think you can split it into rows?

Comment: In the filter, `x` is a single character in the line, but you're testing it as if it's a whole line.

Comment: Maybe you meant to call `ser.readlines()` to read all the lines? But that will wait until it gets EOF, which I don't think will happen on a serial port.

Comment: PI is connected to arduino and it constantly submits actual data each 30 seconds via usb serial. Dataset consists of 8 lines. It is retrieved from usb serial. I need to cut out 2nd and 6th line and its data. 1st is variable lenght float. 6th line is also float and it is gets either 0 or 1 value.

Comment: There's nothing even close to that in the code you posted. It seems like you just posted something that looks like it's processing the serial input, and then expect someone here to write the correct code from scratch.